# Is it possible to write a script that will ssh to client and dump log file, and download it to your server

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, dump

My code below doesn't work,  when ssh to client and dump log file to the server. Please look at the code below.

```
ssh 192.168.0.10
dmesg >>/log.txt
```

Comment: Please tell us how exactly it does not work. Are there any messages? Is there a firewall, i.e. does SSH work at all? Why are you trying to create the file in `/` - with default permissions this may be prohibited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the command to run on the server as part of your `ssh` command. You can then do the output redirection on the client side:

```
ssh 192.168.0.10 'dmesg' >> local_file.log
```

As Khanna111 mentions, this will require a password to be entered (by default), which you can avoid by setting up SSH keys for passwordless login.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing `ssh` to the client and run the `dmesg` command and then `rsync` the logs back. Assuming you can use rsync.

You could also have a `CRON` that periodically run on the client that invokes `dmesg` and dumps the log file which can subsequently be copied over. This way you do not have to do an explict `ssh`.

Another option that I would prefer is to get `rysnc` to run the command "`dmesg`" before the transfer. The parameter to use is `--rsync-path`. The details are explained here: http://www.schwertly.com/2013/07/forcing-rsync-to-create-a-remote-path-using-rsync-path/

EDIT 1: I am assuming that in case of ssh, you have thought about password less logins and the setup they require.

Comment: I had already solve this, please close this question. I am unable to ask question. Thanks everyone.